# Magento 1.9.2.0 Password Reset Page is blank

Tags: magento-1.9

I have an issue with a Magento installation which is causing the Password Reset page (the page immediately following the form POST on the Forgot Password page) is the White Screen of Death. The issue is an old one (several years), as this is based on the files and DB dump of an existing site, and the Password Reset page is broken there, too.

Searching Stack Overflow and Google suggests that the most common cause of this behaviour is an upgrade to 1.6 some time in the past when the customer.xml file was [extended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335106/magento-forgotten-pword-returns-blank-browser-page). Following the advice in that and many other threads, I checked my customer.xml file and the required configuration is there (I diff'd it with the customer.xml file from a fresh Magento download to be sure).

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. The Apache error log shows the following (URL is redacted):

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 1548, referer: https://dev.example.com/customer/account/forgotpassword/

Would anyone have any guidance on how to proceed from here?

Thanks,